# How to stay comfort in airport for a long connecting flight

Tags: air-travel, airports, bookings

I m travelling next week and the airport stay is 12 hours. I am spouse of EEA national in UK with indefinate stay, as per requirement for the country (cypress and lanarca airport) I am in transit one need to transit visa for airport but I checked with embassay and they contracted airport staff who told that

> Under 12 hours stay is fine without spouse of EEA national not having a transit visa.

I wanted to find out what do I need to prepare and how can I make myself comfortable for with 12 hours stay as I cannot leave airport because of visa restriction.

What stuff should I carry for myself and kids because it is hot now a days.

Comment: Even if you state you will have 10 children under the age of 12 with you, or perhaps only 2 children aged 14 and 15, it would still be an opinion.

Comment: Which airport is this, and what's your nationality?

Comment: @Leaderboard lanarca, cypress. I m Pakistani. According to embassy I cannot leave transit area as I do not hold European passport so my option is to stay within.

Comment: Where are you travelling from/to and what airline(s) are involved? Are the two flights actually on a single ticket? There aren’t many possibilities for single-ticket non-EU to non-EU connections in Larnaca.

Comment: Also, what are the times of your flights? Overnight and daytime layovers have different needs. And how old are the kids?

Comment: Larnaca seems like an unusual airport to transit in between flights to/from non-European countries, where exactly are you flying to and from? Do you hold any European visas?

Comment: Also, Pakistani citizens need to have an airport transit visa for any airside transit in Cyprus. https://mfa.gov.cy/requiring-airport-transit-visa.html

Comment: @jcaron I had a letter from airport transit saying if it is less than 12 hours I do not need it.

Comment: I’m not sure who “airport transit” is, but this rule does not seem to exist in either Timatic or Traveldoc, the databases used by airlines agents to decide if they will let you board. Without a transit visa for each passenger, they are quite likely to refuse boarding. Also can you please provide the other details requested in previous comments, especially the times involved?

Comment: @jcaron edited now.

Comment: Please add the other details requested: where from/to, airlines involved, single ticket, times of arrival and departure, age of children…

Comment: I have found your other question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182479/does-the-spouse-of-an-eu-citizen-need-a-transit-visa-for-cyprus which states you are flying LGW-LCA-JED. Google Flights tells me this is likely on Wizz Air, two tickets booked separately. This means Wizz Air in LGW will most likely want proof that you can enter Cyprus, not just transit. Ask for a visa from Cyprus (or Hungary since you return via Budapest) as a spouse of an EEA national, it’s free and must be issued within 15 days. Note that without a real visa you can’t have checked bags.

Comment: @jcaron good point but also I forgot to mention I do not have checked bags, just Rucsack that can fit under chair

Comment: @localhost I think you missed the important point: since the two flights are booked separately (you are doing a self-transfer), Wizz Air in LGW are likely to ignore the transit and consider that your final destination is Larnaca, and require a full visa for entry into Cyprus. If you don’t have a visa for Cyprus, there is a strong possibility that you will be refused boarding.

Comment: @localhost Wizz Air state on their website: “_Wizz Air does not operate connecting flights. In case you have 2 or more separate bookings on the same day, those are considered as non-related reservations and you will be required to leave the transit zone. Therefore, you need to make sure your documents are valid for each country you enter/depart from_”. Even when they sell multiple (separate) tickets themselves they state “_Please note that you might need some special documents or visas allowing you to **enter** the intermediary country (might be different from transfer or transit documents)_”

Comment: @jcaron I had a terrible night. They didn’t let me go, despite showing them letter from embassy. One counter lady said to get a evisa for turkey, which I did and got boarding pass, when they were opening gate the guy didn’t let me go despite me having boarding and letter from embassy

Answer (score 1):

If the airport has a hotel you can get to, rent hotel rooms for the time you are there.
Otherwise you might look in getting into an airline lounge, which sometimes come free with your ticket and in other cases you can buy a day ticket for.

And always search online for the airport and maybe sleeping on airports to see tips for that particular airport.

In most airports you can buy all you need and on your bank  or creditcard, but do check for airport reviews as not all airports are equal.

Added:
This answer was written before the airport was added but as I am not familiar with the airport I can not improve the answer based on that information.